# How to use remove_from_list method of ActiveRecord with scope as public in the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, acts-as-list

Lets say my model is C . Obj - @c

C has acts_as_list gem defined as 
acts_as_list scope: '...'

and scope as :
scope :public -> {where (some_condition)}

When writing rspec for @c.remove_from_list , the test fails with ArgumentError(1 for 0). However, if I rename the scope to any keyword other than public , for ex:

scope :publi -> {where (some_condition)}

the test passes .

PS. I am not passing any arguments in my spec.

Is there a constraint on using scope as public while using aacts_as_list gem ?

Comment: It might be worth checking if there's another method `public` on the model. Also, can you provide a stack trace (at least the `acts_as_list` relevant trace so we know what's calling `public`. You also haven't told us your full `acts_as_list` definition including the scope. We can't do much without that information :)

Comment: Also, you can use backticks to quote your code portions for easier readability.

Comment: There is no  additional method `public` in the model. However on researching a bit more into this realized that the gem `acts_as_list` inserts the method name (in this case `remove_from_list` as an argument in the `public` scope method. Fixed this by placing `(*args)`  in the method definition. Thanks though.

Comment: Did you want to answer your question so that others can benefit from your learning? :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no additional method public in the model. However on researching a bit more into this realized that the gem acts_as_list inserts the method name (in this case remove_from_list as an argument in the public scope method. Fixed this by placing (*args) in the method definition.

Thanks @Brendon Muir for the suggestion.